# CefSharp. When minimize windows form get grey content

Tags: c#, winforms, minimize, cefsharp

I read about CefSharp and it is really great but there is one problem. I want to use CefSharp with windows forms and it runs. When i minimize the windows and then open it again the content is missing. However, when I resized the embedded browser window, the page appeared. Just as it should.

Some pictures:

[Before minimize](http://postimg.org/image/cyze3xqrh/)

[After minimize](http://postimg.org/image/itead4vph/)

I use CefSharp directly from GitHub, can you help me to solve this problem. I will be very thankful if you help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's clearly a bug! (And I just reproduced it on Win7 when I don't maximize the window)

I just happened to see http://www.hjerpbakk.com/blog/2014/10/5/windows-forms-cefsharp-grey-content yesterday

Does adding `Size = Size,` to the [BrowserForm](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/v33.0.0/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserForm.cs#L29https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/v33.0.0/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserForm.cs#L29) constructor fix it for you?

Like this:

```
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(CefExample.DefaultUrl)
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Size = Size,
        };
```

**Update:** Naah forget it that doesn't fix the issue it seems. Please report it as a bug to the CefSharp project so it can be fixed (After all StackOverflow isn't a bug tracker)

**Update2:** It *might* be related to problems with EGL. It looks like a workaround is to remove or rename the `libEGL.dll` in the bin folder. Note a rebuild of the CefSharp.Example.WinForms app will copy it there again!

**Update3:** With CefSharp v33.0.2 this should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you @jornh . When i remove libEGL.dll the program run correctly. I do not know any other solutions but this works for me. If there is any other solution share it here. :)

Comment: @Диян Thanks for confirming that the work-around works for you. I created an issue in the CefSharp project: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/511. I encourage further discussion to happen there!

Comment: @Диян Please, could you do a fresh pull from GitHub and check that you don't need the workaround any more? See the #511 GitHub issue for further details. Thanks!